# Install Java Web Start from an Application

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a simple Java program that uses:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/javaws", [path for JNLP file])
```

to open a JNLP file using java web start.

However, I need to deal with the scenario of javaws not being installed. So I need to check to see if it is installed and, if it's not, install it. Any idea how to do either of those (or both)?

Comment: Isn't Web Start included with every JRE installation?  If you're running in a JVM, surely Web Start is already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're assuming that the path to javaws is `/usr/bin/javaws`, which may not be the case.

If it were that simple, then you can check if the file exists:

```
File javawsFile = new File("/usr/bin/javaws");
if (! javawsFile.exists()) {
    System.out.println("javaws not installed");
}
```

Having said that, java does not have to be installed to any particular location. Thus you can't assume it's in `/usr/bin/`. Many people will download the java binary zip and simply decompress it to their choice of location, and set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`.

Now, you could go down the path of resolving the `JAVA_HOME` variable - but even then it'll only tell you if javaws is installed - or not.

If javaws is not installed, there is not really a way to install it - other than prompting the user to go off to the java website and download it.

The path you give is in *nix style. In this case it would require root access to install new applications - which isn't something you can simply manufacture.

Even if your user was already running your application as root, I would still be wary of this. It's not your responsibility to install software on your users' machines.

Comment: If what you are saying in the 1st 1/2 of your answer was true (which I wholeheartedly agree), than it should be trivial to d/l Java and unpack it to a temp folder with unzip, then set JAVA_HOME and run javaws. Should it not? And how do you know what pr0crstnation101 responsibilities are or are not? I don't, so I'd just suggest that it was possible and leave the rest to himself.

Comment: @ajeh It would be possible to download the javaws application and place it in a temp directory. However, this behaviour sounds typical of spyware or malicious code - you are attempting to install software on a machine that the user has not consented to. Also, downloading the correct version of javaws would be a little tricky. You would have to identify the architecture of the machine and download the correct build of javaws. To summarise this is (A) suspicious behaviour, and  might offend anti-virus software and (B) would be quite tricky to make this reliable across platforms.

Comment: And again, you don't know if the user consented or not, you are just suspecting the asker of doing something wrong. He may be doing it on his corporate network in a controlled environment. Who are we to police the Internet?

Comment: @ajeh, I think he was identifying those items as reasons why it probably isn't possible, not reasons why the OP shouldn't do it.

Comment: yeah, I'm aware that the file path is not necessarily correct; that's another issue I need to tackle. Speaking of which, will using "$ which javaws" work to get me the correct directory for javaws (on my computer it gives me the same directory)? As for installing javaws in the case that it cannot be found, good point re: not installing things in a sketch way. I might end up just telling the user that they need to install it. Thanks.

Comment: @pr0crstnation101 that will work as long as the PATH variable contains the $JAVA_HOME/bin directory - which is not guaranteed. Again - its difficult to come up with a foolproof method as there are many ways to install Java.